# Selenium Python: click on onclick element containing JavaScript

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, onclick, webdriverwait

I'm using Selenium with Python to navigate through a webpage and want to click on such Element:

```
<td style="width:75px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="$(this).up().addClassName('grid-visited'); showIndicator(); document.location.href='/masterdata/show/id/1'">591000397</td>
```

I tried a some stuff which didn't work,
e.g.

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("td[onclick*=pointer]").click()
```

or

```
browser.find_element_by_link_text("591000397").click()
```

Error message be like

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"td[onclick*=pointer]"}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **591000397** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td[contains(@onclick, 'grid-visited') and contains(@onclick, 'masterdata')][text()='591000397']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(@onclick, 'grid-visited') and contains(@onclick, 'masterdata')][text()='591000397']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)